# Unreal Python add material to CachedGeometry

Tags: python, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unrealscript

i can't find the way to assign a material to a CachedGemotry with python scripting.

On staticGeometry i can do it with ".set_material" but the function dont exist on CachedGeometry.

Do you have a solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean [GeometryCache](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/PythonAPI/class/GeometryCache.html) when you talk about CachedGeometry or am I mistaken?

Assuming I'm not (apologies if I am) then you will be able to do this by modifying the 'materials' property on your GeometryCache object.

```
import unreal

# Gets Pre-existing objects
cached_geo_asset = unreal.load_asset(‘<GEO_CACHE_PATH>’) 
mat_asset = unreal.load_asset(‘<MATERIAL_PATH’)

# Display materials before update.
print(‘Before’)
mats = cached_geo_asset.get_editor_property('materials')
print(mats)

# Override the existing materials to use only the one loaded
# above.
cached_geo_asset.set_editor_property('materials', [mat_asset])

# Display materials after update.
print(‘After’)
mats = cached_geo_asset.get_editor_property('materials')
print(mats)
```

I hope this helps! I haven't used GeometryCache much so I would be curious to hear if this solutions works out for you.